# Check Computation of MME and MLE

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, method-of-moments

> Let $X_1$, . . . , $X_n$ be i.i.d random variables having pdf
>
> $$f(x\mid\theta) = (\theta+ 1)x^{\theta}I_{(0,1)}(x)$$
>
> where $\theta \gt−1$
>
> (a) Give a MME of $\theta$ based on the first sample moment.
>
> (b) Give the MLE of $\theta$

**My Attempt:**

(a)

We have

$$\begin{align*}
\mu_1^{'}
& =\int_{0}^{1} (\theta+1)x^{\theta+1}dx\\\\
&=(\theta+1)\frac{x^{\theta+2}}{\theta+2}\Big|_{0}^{1}\\\\
&=\frac{\theta+1}{\theta+2}\\\\
&=1-\frac{1}{\theta+2}
\end{align*}$$

Hence $$\theta=\frac{1-2\mu_1^{'}}{\mu_1^{'}-1}$$

and so

$$\hat{\theta}_{MME}=\frac{1-2\bar{X}}{\bar{X}-1}$$

(b)

We have

$$\begin{align*}
L(\theta\mid\vec{x})
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \left[(\theta+ 1)x^{\theta}I_{(0,1)}(x)\right]\\\\
&=(\theta+1)^n\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{\theta}
\end{align*}$$

Upon taking the natural log of both sides, we get

$$\mathscr{L}(\theta\mid\vec{x})=n\cdot\text{log}(\theta+1)+\theta\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\text{log }x_i\right)$$

Then $$0=\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathscr{L}(\theta\mid\vec{x})=\frac{n}{\theta+1}+\sum_{i=1}^n\text{log }x_i\Rightarrow\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=-\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\text{log }x_i}-1$$

Then

$$\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}\mathscr{L}(\theta\mid\vec{x})=-\frac{1}{(\theta+1)^2}$$

which is negative for all $\theta\in(-1,\infty)$ so $\mathscr{L}(\theta\mid\vec{x})$ is a concave function and the single root of $\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathscr{L}(\theta\mid\vec{x})=0$ must be a local and global maximum.

Are these valid solutions?

Comment: I did not find problem.